# When updating a preprint on arXiv, should I update my affiliation?

Tags: arxiv, affiliation, preprint

I have a preprint on the arXiv, a couple of years old, and will shortly be re-submitting an updated version.  The changes are fairly limited — more than just typos, but not so much as to change the section numbering, let’s say.

I and a co-author are postdocs, and have moved institutions since the original version.  **Should we update the author affiliations as given in the article, or leave them as they are?**

The article hasn’t been published and probably won’t be any time soon (it’s expository, and a bit difficult to find a suitable venue for).  However, it’s been fairly widely read and cited as a preprint.

The field is pure mathematics.

Comment: I'm not sure of the norms here so won't put an answer in, but worth remembering that if you don't feel right updating the affiliations, you could consider adding a footnote - "(*) now at University of X, xxx@yyy.edu" or similar

Comment: If you're using LaTeX, check whether the style file that you use allows for a "current address" in addition to the main affiliation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your affiliation *as far as the work goes* is where the work was done. You should perhaps add a footnote giving your current location, and (obviously) update any contact information given.

Or do it the the other way around: give current affiliation, and in acknowledgements or at least a footnote state where the work was done.

I've seen both.